# Using your own buttons with PayPal API

Tags: javascript, api, paypal, integration

I have a website where I am integrating with PayPal smart button API. I was trying to read up to see if there is a way I can use my own HTML button elements to trigger the API for createOrder and onApprove. It seems PayPal has these calls built into it's button generator. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own buttons, you would need to create a v2/order transaction and redirect the customer to that URL, and then they would be redirected back for you to capture and show a thank you page.

You won't get the benefits of Smart Payment Buttons' in-context / minibrowser checkout with no redirect [(demo pattern)](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).  You also won't get the benefits of the embedded iframe with credit card fields that is available to some.

Comment: It should be possible to handle "redirect the customer to that URL" with an iframe, right?

Comment: *Within* an iframe? No. But to you can use target=_blank or target=_top to escape an iframe, if you are in one for some reason

Comment: I mean if you control the parent page, and use target=<iframe name> to put the payment form in an iframe.  Would PayPal's payment form continue functioning in the iframe, or do something to block/escape the iframe?

Comment: You cannot redirect to PayPal within a frame. You need to either redirect in a top window, or use Smart Payment Buttons to open a minibrowser.

Comment: And a minibrowser is itself a top window... so you wouldn't need Smart Payment Buttons to do that (just the basic JavaScript to open a browser window).  The redirect pageload would be unavoidable (I think), but the minibrowser could still report back to the parent page and close itself.

Comment: Yes if you want to open your own separate minibrowser and direct that to PayPal, I suppose you can. Good luck with such an implementation, it is quite advanced to make something like that work consistently well in all browsers. Virtually every other developer on the internet will opt to not reinvent the wheel and use SPB instead.